# Algorithm for linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have three vectors for example $(1,0,-1)$, $(0,-1,0)$ and $(1,0,4)$ then any linear combination  of two of them is not equal to a third, for any pick of two. This implies that they are linearly independent, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "two of them is not equal to third"? The sum of two, or any linear combination of the two?

Comment: @Magma linear combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true for any tuple of vectors. If they were linearly dependent, then one could be expressed as a linear combination of the others.

Suppose they are linearly dependent. Then there would be a linear combination $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + \ldots + a_nv_n = 0$ such that the $a_i$ aren't all $0$.

Choose an $i$ such that $a_i \neq 0$, and move $a_iv_i$ to the other side of the equation, then divide by $a_i$. What you get is an expression showing that $v_i$ is a linear combination of the other vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm for linear independence is given by computing the *determinant* of the matrix with the corresponding three vectors. In our case, $\det(A)=-5$, which is nonzero in a field $K$ of characteristic zero. Hence the three vectors are linear independent over $K$.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the definitions.  Three vectors, u, v, and w, are said to be linearly **dependent** if and only if there are three numbers,  A, B, and C, not all 0, such that Au+ Bv+ Cw= 0.  If that is true, and C is non-zero, then w= -(A/C)u- (B/C)v.  If B is non-zero, then v= -(A/B)u- (C/B)w.  If A is non-zero then u= -(B/A)v- (C/A)w.  That is, three vectors are linearly dependent if and only if one can be written as a linear combination of the other two.  And they are linearly **independent** if that is not true- if no one of them can be written as a linear combination of the other two.